# Input submit não chama ActionResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

Estou enfrentando problemas para chamar o ActionResult utilizando `input type="submit"` e passar os dados do model.

Fiz um teste utilizando `ActionLink` mas o Model não é enviado.

Alguém poderia dar uma luz?

Segue código:
Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Aprovar(FormularioModel model)
{
//Código
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Devolver(FormularioModel model)
{
//Código
}
```

View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(null, "Domiciliacao", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formFila" })) 
    {
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ViewPartial.cshtml", Model) //PartialView sendo carregada para complentar os dados da tela.
//Código
    <div>               
                    <input type="submit" value="Aprovar" name="Aprovar" formmethod ="post" formaction="~/Domiciliacao/Aprovar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg"/>
                </div>
                <div>                
                    <input type="submit" value="Devolver" name="Devolver" formmethod ="post" formaction="~/Domiciliacao/Devolver" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg"/>
                </div>
    }
```

Comment: Tentou colocar o nome da action?

Comment: Isso é ASP.NET Core?

Comment: Aline: sim coloquei, porem tenho mais de uma action. - JBueno: MVC4

Comment: Então como você define pra qual action está enviando?

Comment: Através do formaction

Comment: Sim, vi ele ali. Mas tu atribui o valor do atributo do botão pro formulário em qual momento? Com js?

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi. sou iniciante no desenvolvimento WEB.

Comment: Você não tem um código que atribui o valor do atributo: formaction pra action do formulário? Todo o seu código é esse que você postou?

Comment: Não é todo, mas se está se referindo a algum <script>, não tenho nessa view. Estou querendo chamar a Action passando todo o Model, com as alterações que foram feitas.

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso.

Alterei algumas coisas no HTML:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formFila" })) 
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/ViewPartial.cshtml", Model){
        <div>               
           <input type="button" value="Aprovar" name="Aprovar" data-formaction="~/Domiciliacao/Aprovar" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-submit"/>
        </div>
        <div>                
           <input type="button" value="Devolver" name="Devolver" data-formaction="~/Domiciliacao/Devolver" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg btn-submit"/>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Usei jquery pra você ver:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#formFila .btn-submit").click(function(){
      var form = $("#formFila");
      form.attr("action", $(this).data("formaction");
      form.submit();
   });
});
```

Se tu for usar com jquery, não esqueça da referência da lib:
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js

Ou, como já foi dada sugestão, tu pode fazer dois forms. Um para cada situação.

Comment: Obrigado Aline, acredito que a melhor forma seria usar o Script mesmo. Criar dois forms no meu caso seria inviável. Vou testar e posto o retorno.

Answer (score 0):

O beginForm utiliza dois parâmetros: Action e Controller.
Exemplo

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SuaAction", "SeuController", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form", @id = "frm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

Comment: Netinho, para os casos que existe mais de uma action. No caso possuo duas Actions, Aprovar e Devolver.

Comment: Faz dois BeginForm um para cada formulário. Caso queira usar o mesmo para formulário para actions distintas dependendo de um condicional recomendo usar Jquery.

Comment: Mas para enviar o Model inteiro via Jquery? como faz, não conheço?

Comment: Dê uma olhada nesse poste, ele te dará um esclarecimento.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/42060555/4312593